# How do I enable the GUI menus in Vim (with iTerm)

Tags: user-interface, vim, compilation

I want to be able to use this Vim plugin that adds a menu to the top menubar.
[image]

From https://github.com/vim-scripts/Headlights

My compile configuration is like this:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Applications/vim-compiled \
            --enable-rubyinterp \
            --enable-pythoninterp \
            --with-features=huge \
            --enable-gui=carbon \
            --with-x
```

However, when I look up `vim --version`, the GUI line still says:

```
Huge version without GUI.
```

I use Vim from within iTerm. It doesn't modify iTerm's menubar at all. I know some of you might suggest using MacVim. I might consider that later, but not now, because I've patched the vanilla Vim source (to enable [`breakindent`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36292/791)) and I'm not yet up to the task of patching the MacVim source from scratch.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the menu even when in console mode.

Put the following commands in your .vimrc file:

```
  if !has("gui_running")
    :source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim 
    :set wildmenu                        
    :set cpoptions-=<
    :set wildcharm=<C-Z>
    :map <F4> :emenu <C-Z>
  endif
```

Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> will start the menu.  You can now use the cursor keys to select
a menu entry.  Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute it.  Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> if you want to cancel.
This does require the `|+menu|` feature enabled at compile time.

For more details see `:help console-menu`.

Answer (score 2):

Hum, this is a GUI menu. Obviously it won't work in iTerm2 or Terminal because there is no menu bar at all from Vim or any other CLI program's point of view.

Terminal emulators usually don't expose their menubars to programs because an actual terminal typically doesn't have a menubar.

From your link (thanks for that by the way) it appears that at least one person has been able to apply the patch to MacVim, if you want a GUI-only function, your best and only bet is to use a GUI Vim.

Answer (score 2):

`:emenu` offers access to menus. Though no mouse, just keyboard.